# Including Custom Proxy Class File in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl, proxy-classes

I am currently running into an issue with adding web references into my Project in VS 2010. The issue is that when I add the web reference, I get a soap.wsdl file and a References.map file. Typically, when the web reference gets added successfully, the References.map file also contains a References.cs and Entities.datasource file which seem to be grouped under the Reference.map file in the Solution Explorer.

The web service I now try to add does not seem to generate correctly and I get the following error:

"Unable to import WebService/Schema. Unable to import binding 'someBinding' from namespace 'someURL'. Unable to import operation 'exportCSVRows'. The datatype http://www.w3.org/2004/11/xmlmime:base64Binary' is missing."

I have read up on how to use wsdl.exe to generate a proxy class manually but how do I use that proxy class back in my project?

Help would be greatly appreciated and I would be more than happy to include any code in case that will help to clarify.